# decode `IEnumerable<uint>` to string made of 1 byte characters (eg., ASCII)

Tags: c#

I'm looking for a more elegant (eg., with less many functions, eg., "copy into contiguous array then reinterpret") or more efficient way (with less complexity) to transcode a `IEnumerable<uint>` (~ array of 32bits int), which is a compact way to represent a `byte[4]` array, into a string as array of 8bits char:

```
public static string UintArraytoString(this IEnumerable<uint> x) =>
    string.Concat(x.Select(o =>
        new string(BitConverter.GetBytes(o).Select(Convert.ToChar).ToArray())));
```

I'm using .net 5.0. I'm open to use unsafe methods too. I think that one may do something like a reinterpretcast, but the `IEnumerable` is not necessarily contiguous.

Comment: what do you mean by `more elegant or more efficient` performance ? memory ? ..etc. you have to be specific.

Comment: @iSR5 more elegant (eg., with less many functions) or more efficient way (with less complexity)

Comment: A performance tip, consider to implement it using `string.Create` - https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.string.create?view=net-5.0

Comment: If it was `uint[] x` not `IEnumerable<uint> x` then it would be look like `public static string UintArraytoString(this ReadOnlySpan<uint> x) => Encoding.ASCII.GetString(MemoryMarshal.Cast<uint, byte>(x));`

Answer (score 3):

Well, I could propose few improvements for you:

1. Try to use SelectMany instead of just Select;
2. No need to call ToArray since the string.Concat could consume IEnumerable;

```
public static string UintArrayToString(this IEnumerable<uint> x) =>
    string.Concat(x.SelectMany(BitConverter.GetBytes).Select(Convert.ToChar));
```